# Steering wheel recognized on old Raspberry Pi but not new Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, raspberry-pi2, evdev

I bought a new Raspberry Pi 2 to take advantage of the faster speed. A program using `evdev` that I have used on my old Raspberry Pi also runs on my new Raspberry Pi.

But a steering wheel that I use `evdev` to access is recognized on my old Raspberry Pi but not on my new one.

Both Raspberry Pis run Raspbian. Is there anything I need to install on my new Raspberry Pi to get it to recognize the steering wheel?

I can't remember installing anything like that on my old Raspberry Pi, but the steering wheel works fine with it.

UPDATE: I tried installing the newest version of Raspbian on my old Raspberry Pi, and the steering wheel didn't work with that. So it's not the new Raspberry Pi that is a problem. It is the new version of Raspbian. It must lack a driver or something. But I don't know how to fix it.

UPDATE2: I found that in the new version of Raspbian the steering wheel is being recognized during booting as a USB device but not as a `/dev/input/event*` or a `/dev/input/js*`.

Comment: This [article](http://news.hopeindustrial.com/2013/using-a-raspberry-pi-with-a-hope-industrial-systems-touch-screen-part-ii-touch-screen-setup/) suggests looking at your `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf` file and running `evtest`.  This [article](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=105018) could also be relevant, (both found by googling "evdev raspian")

Comment: Thanks for the articles, ja.  The second article is me asking the same question on the Raspberry Pi forum, which got some replies but nothing that worked.  The first article was helpful, but I can't see any difference in the referenced file between the old version of Raspbian and the new version. But the steering wheel works on the old version and it doesn't on the new version.